# What happened to FrameTicks?

Tags: plotting

FrameTicks used to support the positioning of strings along the axes of ListPlot.  For example:

```
x1 = 2 Accumulate[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 100]];
x2 = 5 Accumulate[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 100]];

SetOptions[ListPlot, ImageSize -> 500, Frame -> True, Joined -> True, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Red}, {Thick, Blue}}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {-50, 50}}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Progress from Beginning to End", "Red Line", "Descriptive 
 Title", "Blue line"}, LabelStyle -> {12, FontFamily -> "Arial"}];

ListPlot[{x1, x2}, FrameTicks -> {{{0,"Beginning"},{25,"Early"},{50, 
 "Middle"}, {75,"Almost\nFinished"},{100, "Finished"}}, Automatic, None, 
 Automatic}
]
```

[image]

Recently, FrameLable has changed to require ->{{left,right},{bottom,top}]. If I make these changes to FrameLable and re-evaluate ListPlot I get the plot below. FrameTicks doesn't work anymore. What happened? Is the functionality gone? Moved somewhere else?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I didn't even knew you could write it like that in the past. 
But like you already pointed out, the structure is with nested lists for FrameTicks as well

```
{{left,right},{bottom,top}]
```

You should also set the options in the function directly
so we just use it:

```
FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, 
   Automatic}, {{{0, "Beginning"}, {25, "Early"}, {50, "Middle"}, {75,
      "Almost\nFinished"}, {100, "Finished"}}, Automatic}}
```

or with full code:

```
x1 = 2 Accumulate[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 100]];
x2 = 5 Accumulate[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 100]];

ListPlot[{x1, x2}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, 
    Automatic}, {{{0, "Beginning"}, {25, "Early"}, {50, 
      "Middle"}, {75, "Almost\nFinished"}, {100, "Finished"}}, 
    Automatic}}, ImageSize -> 500, Frame -> True, Joined -> True, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Red}, {Thick, Blue}}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {-50, 50}}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Progress from Beginning to End", "Red Line", 
   "Descriptive 
    Title", "Blue line"}, LabelStyle -> {12, FontFamily -> "Arial"}]
```

> [image]

Comment: I should have thought of that. I even gave myself a hint, but I didn't take it.  This capability is valuable because if you have multiple time series with the values occurring on the same days, you can plot them all in ListPlot and annotate the bottom axes with time labels.  It used to be the case that DateListPlot was *really* slow when plotting long time series.  That may not be the case anymore.